# Find the Serialized Integer

Tags: code-golf, string, integer

### Task

Write a program that will take (as input) a positive integer.  It will then count up from `0`, appending each integer to a `String`, only continuing if the length of the `String` is less than the value of the input.

A *serialized* integer is defined as the fully-formed integer with the maximum value belonging to the `String`.  By "fully-formed", the integer should have no missing digits (which would occur if the length constraint of the `String` is met).

The output of the program should be the *serialized* integer for its respective, positive input.

---

### Rules

- It's code golf, so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins!
- Input will always be positive.
- The output must be an integer in base-10 (decimal).
- The program must be 0-indexed.

---

### Example Input | Output

```
   5 | 4   (0 1 2 3 4              - Length of 5)
  11 | 9   (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1  - Length of 11)
  12 | 10  (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 - Length of 12)
1024 | 377 (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...  - Length of 1024)
```

---

### Note(s)

- If you have any questions (or would like me to provide more examples), please comment!
- Inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034478/how-do-i-calculate-the-maximum-serialized-integers-in-1024-length-limit

Comment: suggested test case : `11`

Comment: @Rod Added it, hopefully it makes it easier to understand!

Comment: Adding quote marks to the string in the examples might make it easier to understand that it's a string.

Comment: So the first `N-1` digits of the [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant), with a `0` prepended?

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```js
f=(n,i=s='0')=>(s+=++i)[n]?i-1:f(n,i)
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 value=1 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>0
```

Edit: Saved 3 bytes with some help from @Arnauld.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

Idea to use prefixes from [Jonathan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131942/47066)

```
LηJ€g›O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f59x2r0dNa9IfNezy///f0MDIBAA)

**Explanation**

```
L         # range [1 ... input]
 η        # prefixes
  J       # join each to string
   €g     # get length of each string
     ›    # input is greater than string length
      O   # sum
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 bytes

```
1n@P±X l >U}a
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=MW5AULFYIGwgPlV9YQ==&input=MTAyNA==)

#### Explanation

```
1n@ P± X l >U}a
1nX{P+=X l >U}a
                   Implicit: U = input integer, P = empty string
  X{         }a    Return the first integer X in [0, 1, 2, ...] that returns a truthy value:
    P+=X             Append X to P.
         l >U        Return P.length > U.
                   This returns the first integer that can't fit into the U-char string.
1n                 Subtract 1 from the result.
                   Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>11 10 9</s>  5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ẈÄ<⁸S
```

A monadic link taking a positive integer and returning a non-negative integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hro7DLTaPGncE////39DAyAQA)**

#### How?

```
ẈÄ<⁸S - Link: positive integer, n
Ẉ     - length of (implicit decimal digits) of each of (implicit [1..n])
 Ä    - cumulative sums
   ⁸  - n
  <   - (cumulative sum) less than (n)?
    S - sum
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

Recursive lambda port from @officialaimm's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131930/66418).

```python
f=lambda k,s='',i=1:k>len(s+`i`)and f(k,s+`i`,i+1)or~-i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxDsIgFEDRna94WyGtiRBdmuBWVxc/oGhp@lIE8qDRLv464nhyb9zzErwqZdbOvB6TgbVLumk61LJfL856ntoRR2H8BDOv8a8OWykCfQ9YMu09g/eCzsKdNlsBkdDneqOPW@ZCMPt52phhuF0HokD1iSalcmZSMqmYPKrTDw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>60 59</s> 58 bytes

- Thanks @Felipe for 2 bytes

```python
i,j,k='',1,input()
while len(i+`j`)<k:i+=`j`;j+=1
print~-j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1MnSyfbVl1dx1AnM6@gtERDk6s8IzMnVSEnNU8jUzshK0HTJtsqU9sWyLLO0rY15CooyswrqdPN@v/f0BgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](http://haskell.org/), <s>55</s> <s>53</s> 50 bytes

```hs
(n#x)a|l<-a++show x=last$x-1:[n#l$x+1|length l<=n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyNPOVGzoibHRjdRW7s4I79cocI2J7G4RKVC19AqOk85R6VC27AmJzUvvSRDIcfGNi/2f25iZp6CrUJKPpcCEBQUZeaVKKgoaJgqKylpKhigChoaYhU1wipqYGQCEVf4DwA)

Usage is `(1024#"") 0`

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 56 bytes

```php
for(;$argn>$l=strlen($r);)$r.=+$i++;echo$i-1-($argn<$l);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxCoMwFAXQ3c@QNyQEC5mfaYeSwcUu3UUkNYGQPK7O/fUIrocjUdr4kihdACoWBKk4U9nV3y/z5zu9veaOVuzF9db23H4Vim94UnbHiRyKImjWhIczlIzhsMVKabCDuuNIWXNrFw)

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
tf<Q=+d
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tf%3CQ%3D%2Bd&input=11&test_suite_input=1%0A5%0A11%0A12%0A1024&debug=0) [Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tf%3CQ%3D%2Bd&input=11&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A5%0A11%0A12%0A1024&debug=0)

Comment: I love it! Using slicing as a comparison is brilliant.

Comment: @isaacg It's one of the nice golf features of Pyth(on). I got the idea when I saw [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131951/30164) (indexing instead of slicing, but same idea). `< num seq` was also very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 36 bytes

```
{(0...^{([~] 0..$^a).comb>$_})[*-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNAT08vrlojui5WAchUiUvU1EvOz02yU4mv1YzW0jWMrf1vrVCcWKmQpmFoYGSiaf0fAA)

- `0 ...^ {...}` is the sequence of numbers from zero until one less than the number for which the code block in braces returns true.  (`...` without the caret would return the first number for which the block returned true.)
- `[~] 0 .. $^a` is the concatenation of numbers from `0` up to the current number `$^a` (the parameter to the code block).
- `.comb` is a list of all of the characters (digits) in the concatenated string.  Interpreted as a number, it evaluates to the length of the string.  `.chars` would be more natural to use here, since it evaluates directly to the length of the string, but the name is one character longer.
- `$_` is the argument to the top-level function.
- `[*-1]` selects the last element of the generated list.

Answer (score 2):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 34 bytes

```
{A=!p$~_lB+A|>:|_xp-1|\B=B+A]p=p+1
```

### Explanation

```
{           DO infinitely
A=!p$       Set A$ to p cast to num
            Note that p starts out as 0.
~      >:   IF the input number is exceeded by
 _l   |     the length of
   B+A      A$ and B$ combined
_xp-1|      THEN QUIT, printing the last int successfully added to B$
            The _X operator quits, (possibly) printing something if followed by a-zA-Z
            _x is slightly different, it prints the expression between the operator _x and |
\B=B+A      ELSE add A$ to B$
]           END IF
p=p+1       Raise p, and rerun
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
f=lambda k,i=0:-2*(k<0)or-~f(k-len(`i`),i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYqxDoMgFAB3voIRWm2AtIvR0a5d@gFai/FFBPJ4pnXpr1MuueGSiwctwZsMWwxIPB2JFS/JEtppxwTBO9iAhFYFmefOjdvrPfK1gk41tTmJtVUyYP2bxVo768UAg6zgrGUmPBrGPws4y5@42xI8InjiswAfdxJSMvudbCTeP@49YsDyxDGlrNmNac20YVqZ6x8)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 26 bytes

```
(>i:1:)([:+/\[:>.10^.1+i.)

((>i:1:)([:+/\[:>.10^.1+i.))"0 ] 5 11 12 1024 2000 20000 100000 1000000
4 9 10 377 702 5276 22221 185184
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 43 bytes

```r
n=scan();sum(cumsum(floor(log10(1:n))+1)<n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcVBDoIwEAXQfU/hcn7cMA1uUJZegMgBCKnYpExJB9SEcPYCi5eXstbuPyWn6qPQmqXWvhPCXZeR@mU8e4cYE4U4cEFcCXBlPAR5g/l9fHD0atonLlPyMpP7doEUMDdjmA/2UNgy7w)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
#ȯ<¹ṁLŀḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9odXNr//8jyK88wrnhuYFMxYDhuKP///8xMDI0)

About as hard as I could condense it. Pyth is really hard to beat here.

Comment: Hard to beat, but at least [possible to match](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225327/95126)...

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
#<¹∫mLḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8b@yzaGdjzpW5/o83LH4////0aY6hoY6hkY6hgZGJrEA)

**How?**

```
      ḣ    # range from 1..input;
    mL     # get the lengths of string representations of each element;
   ∫       # get the cumulative sums;
#          # how many of these
 <¹        # are less than the input?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 5 bytes

```
ʁvL¦>
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%CA%81vL%C2%A6%3E&inputs=1024&header=&footer=)

```
ʁ     # 0...n 
 vL   # Get length of each 
   ¦  # Cumulative sums
    > # (input) is greater than each?
      # (s flag) sum ToS at end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
{(+\#'$!x)'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJx1zsEOgjAMBuD7nqJGEliMuA4mQl/BN0ASPDg0GkkIhxHEZ7fuJEZ3+demX1pbjNHqsAyDhZOhm4ToizEoh2dXWABwVLdXimp7vNzI0UCdrCbRl4bSigORcp+aUPmP0iklWVYJsRHsDTwg5YwUIGhIfPHx1rA/3Zv+DK0FI1kgssjnwsAWMthxG+cC0RPNBNU/ouZES/E+kgmf+YvEcfy1hcflCz1QQbc=)

Takes input `n` as `x`.

- `(...)'x` run a binary search (returning the index of the largest value equal to or smaller than `x`) on the list generated by...
- `(+\#'$!)`

  - `$!x` stringify each value from `0..x-1`
  - `#'` count the number of characters in each stringified number
  - `+\` take the cumulative sums

Answer (score 0):

## [WendyScript](http://felixguo.me/wendy/), 42 bytes

```
<<f=>(x){<<n=""#i:0->x{n+=i?n.size>=x/>i}}

f(1024) // returns 377
```

[Try it online!](http://felixguo.me/#wendyScript)

### Ungolfed:

```
let f => (x) {
  let n = ""
  for i : 0->x { 
    n+=i
    if n.size >= x 
    ret i
  }
  ret
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 41 bytes

```php
while(strlen($s.=+$i++)<=$argn);echo$i-2;
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b92183c3c7c57cf55f4804879826bcf172a50b2).

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 64 bytes

```java
n->{int i=0;for(String t="0";;t+=++i)if(t.length()>n)return~-i;}
```

Or slight alternatives with the same byte-count:

```java
n->{int i=0;for(String t="";;t+=i++)if(t.length()>n)return i-2;}
n->{int i=-1;for(String t="";;t+=++i)if(t.length()>n)return~-i;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hZDBCoJAEIbvPcXQaRdRLOq02BvkxWN02LbVxmyUdQwi7NVtTa8hzAzM/D8fP1Pqpw7rxlJ5vQ@m0m0LR430XgEgsXW5NhbScf0dwIhxklT@0vv21bJmNJACQQIDhYf3aMEkVnntRMYOqQBO1vFaKQ6SIECJueCoslTwTcgDSWe5c/QJUfWDmqhNd6k8dYY/a7zCwwebeaczaDmlyl4t20dUdxw1XuKKBEVG7OUv4199s1kybJcM8XYn50f0wxc)

```java
n->{                  // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int i=0;            //  Integer `i`, starting at 0
  for(String t="0";   //  String, starting at "0"
      ;               //  Loop indefinitely
       t+=++i)        //    After every iteration: append the String with `i+1`
                      //    by first increasing `i` by 1 with `++i`
    if(t.length()>n)  //   If the length of the String is larger than the input:
      return~-i;      //    Return `i-1`
                      //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
}                     // End of method
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 44 bytes

Inspired by Kevin Cruijssen's JAVA answer. -4 bytes thanks to G B.

```
->n{i,t=0,'';t+="#{i+=1}"while t.size<n;i-1}
```

Comment: (i+=1;t+=i.to_s) is the same as t+="#{i+=1}", only 4 bytes longer

Comment: And if you do that, you don't need the variable t anymore, you can subtract the size from n and then compare with 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
->n{~-(0..n).find{|x|0>n-="#{x}"=~/$/}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vuk5Xw0BPL09TLy0zL6W6pqLGwC5P11ZJubqiVsm2Tl9Fv7b2f0FpSbFCWrRpLBeUZWiIYBohmAZGJrH/AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 31 + 1 (`-p`) = 32 bytes

```perl
$".=++$\while$_>=length$"}{$\--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FSc9WW1slpjwjMydVJd7ONic1L70kQ0WptlolRlf3/3/Tf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)